# How to add line to point shapes in ggplot2 legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I want to create a black and white plot using `ggplot2`, where the data is plotted by category using a combination of lines and points. However, the legend *only* shows the point shape, with no line running through it, unless I add color to the plot.

Here is some example data to illustrate the problem with:

```r
## Create example data
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(
    time_period = rep(1:4, each = 3),
    category = rep(LETTERS[1:3], 4),
    y = rnorm(12)
)
```

Here is an example of a color plot, so you can see how I want the legend to look:

```r
library(ggplot2)
## Generate plot with color
ggplot(data = dat, mapping = aes(x = time_period, y = y, color = category)) +
    geom_line(aes(group = category)) +
    geom_point(aes(shape = category), size = 2) +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

However, if I move to grayscale (which I need to be able to do), the line running through the point in the legend disappears, which I'd like to avoid:

```r
## Generate plot without color
ggplot(data = dat, mapping = aes(x = time_period, y = y)) +
    geom_line(aes(group = category)) +
    geom_point(aes(shape = category), size = 2) +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

How can I add a line through the point symbols in the legend with a grayscale plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this approach:

```
#Plot
ggplot(data = dat, mapping = aes(x = time_period, y = y,group = category,shape = category)) +
  geom_line(color='gray',show.legend = T) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  theme_bw()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @duckmayr I hope that helped dear Duck! If you think this was useful you could accept this answer :)

Comment: Of course @Duck -- trick to tick the checkmark immediately, but it said I had to wait 8 minutes (at the time, I think 6 or so more minutes now). From one duck to another, thanks again :)

Comment: Oh you are right :) You will have to wait ! And from one Duck to another, many thanks too :)